# adding another node to a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

[image]I am using a numberline code from @Alain Matthes it works perfectly but I don't understand it enough to add another node, eg start, middle, end instead of just start end. Can anybody point me to the right package document info to understand the foreach when using pgfmathsmacro included in the code. Any help would be amazing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoright}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#1-2,0)--(#2+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}  
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2-1} 
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
     (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
} ; 
\node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
\node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}
\node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-#1\relax\ units to the      \emph{right}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoleft}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=135,in=45,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#2-2,0)--(#1+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#2-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2+1} 
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
    (\i,0) to  (\i-1,0)
 } ; 
 \node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End };
 \node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start };
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}     
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr-#2+#1\relax\ units to the     \emph{left}};
 \end{tikzpicture}} 


 \begin{document}

 \addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{-1}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

 \addsubnumlinetoleft{2}{-4}{->,color=MidnightBlue}  
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot and indicate your desired result?

Comment: If the body of a `\foreach` loop shall contain more than one TikZ command it needs to be put in braces, i.e. `\foreach \x in {<list>} {\draw <something>; \node …;}`.

Comment: To the voters: OP [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656351/adding-another-node-to-a-number-line/656397#comment1635512_656361) that they wanted to place another dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty to rewrite the `\tikznumberline` command.

You can now use the following keys to change the number line and its labels:

- `start` and `end` specify the points on the line that shall be connected (start is always lower than end).
- `tick length` specifies half the height of the ticks.
- `overhang` defines the additional length of the number line left of `start - 1` and right of `end + 1`.
- `direction=left` or `direction=right` instruct the macro on the direction of the arrow.
- `add edge label=<val>[<options>]<text>` can be used to add another node similar to "Start" and "End" below the value `<val>` with the mandatory `<options>` and the text `<text>`.
- `add edge dot=<val>[<options>]` adds a dot on the line at the value `<val>` with the mandatory options `<options>`.
- `add edge node=<val>[<options>]<text>` adds a node to on the line connecting `<val>-1` and `<val>` with the mandatory options `<options>` and the text `<text>`.

More keys and styles are defined which can be used to change the appearence of the number line:

- `start dot` and `end dot` can be used to change the small dots at the `start` and at the `end`, e.g. `\tikznumberlineset{start dot/.append style={fill=Cerulean}`
- `line` for the number line and `ticks` for the ticks (mostly color and line thickness).
- `edge node` for the nodes along the line and `edge node <val>` for the nodes along the line between `<val> - 1` and `<val>` (will be used by the nodes added by `add edge node` and `add edge label`).

### Code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% arrows.meta for the uptodate arrow tips
% shapes.misc for the cross out shape
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.misc, bending}
\newcommand*\tikznumberlineset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/number line}}
\tikznumberlineset{
  arrow/.style={/tikz/>={#1}},
  start/.initial=1, end/.initial=5,
  tick length/.initial=2pt, overhang/.initial=.75,
  %
  % Nodes
  start-end dot/.style={% those are the dots
    shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=+4pt,
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, node contents=},
  %% defaults for "start dot" and "end dot"
  start dot/.style=number line/start-end dot,
  end dot/.style  =number line/start-end dot,
  %% number below the ticks
  value node/.style={
    below=2pt, font=\footnotesize, node contents=$\tikznumberlinevalue$},
  %% text above diagram
  instruction node/.style={
    anchor=south, yshift=5pt, font=\small, node contents=%
      Move \nlvo{units text} to the \emph{\nlvo{direction text}}.},
  %
  % 'Start' and 'End' node, "start-end label"
  % can be used for additional labels
  start-end label/.style={font=\small,yshift=-.75cm},
  start label/.style={number line/start-end label,
    text=Cerulean,node contents=Start},
  end label/.style  ={number line/start-end label,
    text=OrangeRed,node contents=End},
  %
  % Lines, can be used to change color, thickness, etc.
  line/.style ={draw,<->},
  ticks/.style=draw,
  connection/.style={draw=MidnightBlue,out=45,in=135},
  %
  % direction=left or direction=right
  %% the direction changes
  %%  * the arrow tip
  %%  * the text left/right in the instruction and
  %%  * where "Start" and "End" will be set.
  direction text/.initial=, units text/.initial=,
  direction/.is choice,
  direction/left/.style={
    connection/.append style=<-, direction text=left,
    label left/.style =number line/end label,
    label right/.style=number line/start label},
  direction/right/.style={
    connection/.append style=->, direction text=right,
    label left/.style =number line/start label,
    label right/.style=number line/end label},
  direction=right,% default
  %
  % to doesn't like foreach, going to use .list
  % which uses foreach internally
  @toloop/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\tikznumberlinevalue{#1},% make #1 available
    insert path={to[number line/edge/.try,number line/edge #1/.try] (#1,0)}},
  add edge node/.style args={#1[#2]#3}{edge #1/.append style={
    edge node={node
      [number line/edge node/.try,number line/edge node #1/.try,#2]{#3}}}},
  add edge label/.style args={#1[#2]#3}{
    add edge node={#1[number line/start-end label,at end,#2]#3}},
  add edge dot/.style args={#1[#2]}{
    add edge node={#1[number line/start-end dot,behind path,at end,#2]}},
  all dots/.style={edge/.append style={
    edge node={node[number line/start-end dot,at end,#1]{}}}},
  all dots/.default=}
\newcommand*\tikznumberline[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikznumberlineset{#1}
  \newcommand*\nlvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/number line/##1}}
  \pgfmathint{\nlvo{end}-(\nlvo{start})}
  \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/number line/units text}{\pgfmathresult}
  %
  % 1. The lines and the ticks:
  \path[number line/ticks] (\nlvo{start}-1-\nlvo{overhang},\nlvo{tick length})
             grid[ystep=0] (\nlvo{end}+1+\nlvo{overhang},-\nlvo{tick length});
  \path[number line/line] (\nlvo{start}-1-\nlvo{overhang},0)
                       -- (\nlvo{end}+1+\nlvo{overhang},0);
  %
  % 2. the black circles (these are nodes now)
  %    and the labels "Start" and "End"
  \path (\nlvo{start},0) node (@number line@start) [number line/start dot]
                         node [number line/label left]
        (\nlvo{end},0)   node (@number line@end)   [number line/end dot]
                         node [number line/label right];
  %
  % 3. the numbers below the ticks
  \foreach \tikznumberlinevalue[expand list]
    in {\the\numexpr\nlvo{start}-1\relax,...,\the\numexpr\nlvo{end}+1\relax}
      \node at (\tikznumberlinevalue,0) [number line/value node];
  %
  % 4. the hopping line which is fully connected, no movetos anymore
  %    the last edge is available via the last edge key if one needs to add
  \path[number line/connection](@number line@start)
    [number line/@toloop/.list/.expanded={%
      \the\numexpr\nlvo{start}+1\relax,...,\the\numexpr\nlvo{end}-1\relax}]
    to[number line/last edge/.try] (@number line@end);
  % 5.
  \node at ({(\nlvo{start}+\nlvo{end})/2},\nlvo{tick length})
    [number line/instruction node];
\end{tikzpicture}}

\tikznumberlineset{arrow=Stealth}
\tikzset{small cross out/.style={
  cross out,at end,minimum size=2mm,draw=gray,ultra thick,line cap=round}}
\begin{document}
\tikznumberline[start=-5, end=-1,
  add edge node={-4[small cross out]},
]
\tikznumberline[start=-4, end= 2, direction=left,
  add edge label={0[green]Middle},
  add edge node={-1[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily]Hip},
  add edge node={-2[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily]Hop},
  add edge dot={0[green]}
]
\tikznumberline[all dots=blue]
\tikznumberline[
  start=-15, end=10, /tikz/x=5mm, /tikz/arrows={[bend]},
  value node/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=east, inner xsep=.1em},
  start dot/.append style=Cerulean, end dot/.append style=OrangeRed,
  all dots={
    minimum size=+3pt,
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{100*(\tikznumberlinevalue-\nlvo{start})/
                                  (\nlvo{end}-\nlvo{start})},
    fill/.expanded=OrangeRed!\pgfmathresult!Cerulean}
]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Should the dot not be behind the curved line, remove `behind path` from `add edge dot`. Should it default to black just say `add edge dot={0[]}` or define your own key/style. This is also possible: `\tikznumberline[add edge dot/.list={2[],...[],4[]}]`

Comment: Thanks so much, I do love this platform especially when people go all out to teach fools like me what is going on in the answers you give.

Comment: @PaulA No problem. I've edited my answer and replaced `\numberlinevalue` with `\tikznumberlinevalue` while making `\tikznumberlinevalue` available inside the `.list` loop and added an `all dots` style that adds the same dots on all integers between start and end. When used with a value, the style adds that value to the dots. In the last example I've shown what can be doable with that.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

Changes in comparison to your code are in MWE below marked by `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoright}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#1-2,0)--(#2+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2-1}
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
     (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
} ;
\pgfmathparse{(#2+#1)/2}    % <---
\node[color=OrangeRed]  at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
\node[color=green]      at (\pgfmathresult,-0.75) {\small Middle};  % <---
\node[color=Cerulean]   at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}
\node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-#1\relax\ units to the \emph{right}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoleft}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[out=135,in=45,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#2-2,0)--(#1+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#2-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2+1}
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
    (\i,0) to  (\i-1,0)
 } ;
\pgfmathparse{(#2+#1)/2}    % <---
\node[color=OrangeRed]  at (#2,-0.75) {\small End };
\node[color=green]      at (\pgfmathresult,-0.75) {\small Middle};  % <---
\node[color=Cerulean]   at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start };
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr-#2+#1\relax\ units to the \emph{left}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}   

    \addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{-1}{->,color=MidnightBlue}
    \medskip\newline
    \addsubnumlinetoleft{2}{-4}{->,color=MidnightBlue}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help and it will come in handy at another point, but I should have phrased my question differently.  What I would like should have been phrased, can I add another dot 1st, 2nd, 3rd dots on the number line, not necessarily in the middle of the start and end.